# Cache Busting on Mobile Browsers

Tags: javascript, caching, http-headers

### The Problem

A handful of users (mobile only) have old versions of JavaScript files even though the header of `index.html` is set to

`cache-control: max-age=0, must-revalidate`

and the JavaScript has a unique path for each new deployment `[randomString].app.js` and I've issued a Cache Invalidation on AWS CloudFront where the static files are being hosted.

### A Possible Suspect

I believe this is because if a mobile browser leaves a tab open (as it is easy to do with safari on mobile, people rarely reboot or close all their tabs), then the client would not request the new index.html and thus not get the new JavaScript.

### Question

Is there any way to ensure that users with long-lived tabs (multiple weeks) still get the latest code?  Or could the cause of the users having outdated JavaScript be something else?

Comment: I know some sites like Google Drive sometimes block the view with an alert "Drive is outdated. Please reload the page". Not sure how they do it, though. Maybe simply "After a certain date, ask the user to reload the page"

Comment: That's a good idea, I suppose if all my cache headers are correct, prompting them to refresh a long-lived tab might be the only solution - and it shouldn't require a hard refresh.

Comment: @Jordan how did you end up solving this? Did you manage to implement the suggestion from Jeremy? Or did you do something else? Do you track session duration?

Comment: @aviya.developer, I made an endpoint on the backend that would return the expected version of the frontend (via package.json).  Then whenever the page regained focus (or on a navigation event) I would make a request to that endpoint and compare the current version with the expected version.  If they were out of sync, I would show a banner prompting the user to refresh their page.

Comment: @Jordan very nice! I was thinking of returning a "Cache Buster" `302` if the updated API endpoint receives an old packet. But I like your way of generally having a monitor on. Thanks for the reply!